# what are the constraints for std::ranges::make_heap?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

The following code works well with gcc:

```
struct S {
  int i, j;
  auto operator<(const S& s) const {
    return i < s.i;
  };
};
std::vector<S> v;
std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
```

But when I switch to C++20's range algorithm:

```
std::ranges::make_heap(v);
```

[I got this compiler error:](https://godbolt.org/z/WeGc44)

```
source>:14:27: error: no match for call to '(const std::ranges::__make_heap_fn) (std::vector<S>&)'
14 |   std::ranges::make_heap(v);
   |    
                   ^
```

It seems `struct S` doesn't satisfy the requirements of the `ranges::make_heap`, but I don't know what exactly it is, can someone help?

Comment: Find the intended overload in the error message and look at the failed constraint that is elaborated upon for that overload.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::ranges::make_heap` uses [`std::ranges::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ranges/less), which has a constraint:

> Unlike `std::less`, `std::ranges::less` requires all six comparison operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==` and `!=` to be valid (via the `totally_ordered_with` constraint).

Your type `S` does not have an equality operator; the spaceship operator only provides the other comparison operators.*

To fix this, provide an `operator==` for your type:

```
constexpr auto operator==(const S& s) const {
  return i == s.i;
}
```

Godbolt Link: https://godbolt.org/z/cGfrxs

* `operator<=>` does not imply `operator==` for performance reasons, as `operator==` can short circuit over collections whereas `operator<=>` cannot. However, from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons , we see that a defaulted `operator<=>` will also implicitly default an `operator==`.

---

How did I figure this out? The error message for your code includes the following (trimmed and word wrapped by me):

> ```
> note: the expression 'is_invocable_v<_Fn, _Args ...>
>     [with _Fn = std::ranges::less&; _Args = {value_type&, value_type&}]'
>     evaluated to 'false'
>   338 |     concept invocable = is_invocable_v<_Fn, _Args...>;
>       |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

This means that `std::ranges::make_heap` finds that it can't call `std::ranges::less` for our type. Repeating this error message investigation for `std::ranges::less` on the `value_type` of the vector yields:

> ```
> note: no operand of the disjunction is satisfied
>   123 |       requires totally_ordered_with<_Tp, _Up>
>       |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   124 |         || __detail::__less_builtin_ptr_cmp<_Tp, _Up>
> ```

At this point, the compiler is trying hard to tell us that we aren't satisfying `totally_ordered_with`, which means that it's time to hit the documentation for the concept and for `std::ranges::less`.

Comment: Adding `==` does fix the problem here, but I don't think the explanation is right. e.g. It [works](https://godbolt.org/z/eje3a4) if `<=>` is defaulted.

Comment: @cigien Indeed, the spaceship operator works a bit differently than I thought, providing an `operator==` if it is defaulted. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons : "If `operator<=>` is defaulted and `operator==` is not declared at all, then `operator==` is implicitly defaulted. "

Comment: Ah, nice catch. I think that explains it :) You might want to mention that. Something like "since you have a non-defaulted `<=>`, the `==` is not generated".