C++20: strange difference between std::less() and std::ranges::less()
So, I have different behaviour for range and non-range versions of less functor. That's a minimal code example to reproduce the behaviour:
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

class Int
{
public:
   Int(int d) : m_data(d) {}

   auto operator<=>(const Int& other) const {
      return this->m_data <=> other.m_data;
   }

private:
   int m_data;
};

int main()
{
   Int x(15);
   Int y(17);

   std::invoke(std::less(), x, y);         // OK, compiles well
   std::invoke(std::ranges::less(), x, y); // ERROR, does not compile
}

If you replace Int class with a primitive type like int, everything will be fine and will work as expected.
I've got a comiler error at the std::invoke(std::ranges::less(), x, y); line.
Error for Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 17.9.6
    Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Ty1 &&,_Types2 &&...) noexcept(<expr>)'
        C:\Users\C-401\Desktop\test\heap_test\heap_test.cpp(24,9):
        With the following template arguments:
            C:\Users\C-401\Desktop\test\heap_test\heap_test.cpp(24,9):
            '_Callable=std::ranges::less'
            C:\Users\C-401\Desktop\test\heap_test\heap_test.cpp(24,9):
            '_Ty1=Int &'
            C:\Users\C-401\Desktop\test\heap_test\heap_test.cpp(24,9):
            '_Types2={Int &}'
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\type_traits(1736,50):
        'std::_Invoker_functor::_Call': no matching overloaded function found
            C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\type_traits(1633,27):
            could be 'unknown-type std::_Invoker_functor::_Call(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept(<expr>)'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\type_traits(1727,19):
or       'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&) noexcept(<expr>)'
    C:\Users\C-401\Desktop\test\heap_test\heap_test.cpp(24,9):
    'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&) noexcept(<expr>)': expects 1 arguments - 3 provided

Error for gcc (looked via cppinsights . io service)
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/functional:110:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Callable = std::ranges::less, _Args = <Int &, Int &>]: no type named 'type' in 'std::invoke_result<std::ranges::less, Int &, Int &>'
  110 |     invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
      |     ^

Some background info
Originally I faced that problem when I noticed that I am not able to use std::ranges::make_heap(), std::ranges::push_heap() and std::ranges::pop_heap() for my std::vector<T> where T type is quite like the Int in the code above - it contains several members and type should be comparable only by of these members, so I have the same operator<=> there. I've dug deep the template errors I've got and discovered that originally error is caused by the less function, but now I'm kinda stuck to explain the cause of the error

Your class doesn't support == (and !=, but you don't need to define the latter manually when you have the former). std::ranges::less wants a full set of comparison operators, even though it doesn't use them.

@HolyBlackCat wow, that was really fast :) and it solved the problem indeed. I wander though why it wasn't enough to provide operator<=> and why std::less is less (sorry for the pun) restrictive? Anyway I would be pleased to accept your answer if you'll provide it

I'm sure there's been a lot of duplicate questions about this, try to find one..

@康桓瑋 well, I'll be gratefull to see them, since I didn't find any at the moment of asking

Okay, I found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708867/what-are-the-constraints-for-stdrangesmake-heap thanks to everyone anyway

As for why <=> doesn't generate ==, that's because a handwritten one can be more efficient (e.g. string's == can compare length early and exit if not equal, while <=> can't).
